# Linear combination of Geometric Brownian Motions

Tags: probability, finance

Let $X_t= e^{\left(\mu-\sigma^2/2 \right)t+\sigma W_t}$ be a geometric Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and volatility $\sigma$. I am trying to derive an analytical solution to

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \max(a X_T + b X_S -K,0)\right],$$
where $a$, $b$ and $K$ are constants and $0<S<T$.

My objective is to find the critical point as from which $aX_T + bX_S$ will be greater than $K$ so that I can disregard the maximum function and evaluate the expectation.

Am I right to say that if I had only $Y= X_T + X_S$, I could use the relation $X_T + X_S=2X_S + X_T - X_S$ to find its mean and variance and subsequently find the critical point?

Is there any way to proceed in the same way for my original problem?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean more by the "critical point", and how you would use that to "derive an analytical solution"?

Comment: For example, let's consider $\mathbb{E}[\max(X_T-K,0)]$. Since $X_t$ follows a GBM, I set $Y_T=\log(X_T/X_0)$ to follow a normal distribution with mean $(\mu-\sigma^2/2)T$ and variance $\sigma^2 T$.

The critical point was the value of $Y_T$ as from which $X_T=X_0 \exp(Y_T) \ge K$. Then, instead of integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ to find the expectation, we integrate from the critical point to $\infty$ and express the solution in terms of the CDF of the normal distribution.

I am trying to do something similar for the expectation stated in the question.